# How to make hyperlink in tooltip text reachable in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, htmlwidgets

I would like to make a clickable hyperlink in a tooltip text in ggplotly. The hyperlink does seem to appear in the tooltip, but it can't be clicked. Before I can click, the tooltip dissappears. How can I make the tooltip appear long enough for me to click the hyperlink?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
mtcars$hyperlink <- "<a href='https://plot.ly/ggplot2/'>plotly ggplot2 website</a>"
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, text = hyperlink)) + 
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

You will notice the unclickable hyperlink. Has anyone an idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`paste0("<a href='",lu_url,"' target='_blank'>",lu_url,"","</a>"))` works for me ... but now the tooltip disappears when the cursor moves :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).